# Creating two txt file for changed and unchanged records

Tags: java, file

Hello developers i have a got a code which is compares two txt files find their differences and notes them but i am wanting to add a feature which creates two txt files first one is for changed records and other one is for unchanged records what should i do here? Here is my code:

````java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class B
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        //Getting the name of the files to be compared.
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter 1st File name:");
        String str = br2.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd File name:");
        String str1 = br2.readLine();

        String s1="";
        String s2="", s3="", s4="";
        String y="", z="";

        //Reading the contents of the files
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str));
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str1));

        while((z = br1.readLine()) != null)
            s3 += z;

        while((y = br.readLine()) != null)
            s1 += y;

        System.out.println();

        //String tokenizing
        int numTokens = 0;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1);
        String[] a = new String[10000];
        for(int l = 0; l < 10000; l++)
        {
            a[l]="";
        }
        int i=0;
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            s2 = st.nextToken();
            a[i] = s2;
            i++;
            numTokens++;
        }

        int numTokens1 = 0;
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(s3);
        String[] b = new String[10000];
        for(int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
        {
            b[k]="";
        }
        int j=0;
        while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            s4 = st1.nextToken();
            b[j] = s4;
            j++;
            numTokens1++;
        }

        //comparing the contents of the files and printing the differences, if any.
        int x=0;
        for(int m=0;m<a.length;m++)
        {
            if(!a[m].equals(b[m]))
            {
                x++;
                System.out.println(a[m] + " -- " + b[m]);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of differences : " + x);
        if(x > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Files are not equal");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review SE! This site is for reviewing already working code for improvements and optimizations, not solving problems with broken code or other issues. In fact, the tour page mentions that asking how to add features is off-topic for this site. Stack Overflow may be of more help; however, "write code for me" is out of scope there too. You should try to code this yourself first, and if you are running into issues, Stack Overflow is the apporpriate place to ask.

Comment: I agree with @hyper-neutrino, please see the [help/on-topic] if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Welcom to Code Review!

As @hyper-neutrino pointed, this site is to review working code. As such, here are some tips to improve the code you've provided:

## Naming

Names are absolutely fundamental to help other developers (or even yourself after not working with the code while). So, to improve your code, the first step could be to use better names. For example:

```java
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileComparatorBetterNames {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Getting the name of the files to be compared.
        BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter 1st input filename: ");
        String inputFilename1 = stdinReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd input filename: ");
        String inputFilename2 = stdinReader.readLine();

        String file1Lines = "";
        String file2Lines = "";
        String file1Line = "";
        String file2Line = "";

        //Reading the contents of the files
        BufferedReader file1Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename1));
        BufferedReader file2Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename2));

        while((file1Line = file1Reader.readLine()) != null)
            file1Lines += file1Line;

        while((file2Line = file2Reader.readLine()) != null)
            file2Lines += file2Line;

        System.out.println();

        //String tokenizing
        StringTokenizer file1Tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(file1Lines);
        String[] file1Tokens = new String[10000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            file1Tokens[i] = "";
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (file1Tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            file1Tokens[j] = file1Tokenizer.nextToken();;
            j++;
        }

        StringTokenizer file2Tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(file2Lines);
        String[] file2Tokens = new String[10000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            file2Tokens[i]="";
        }
        j = 0;
        while (file2Tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            file2Tokens[j] = file2Tokenizer.nextToken();
            j++;
        }

        //comparing the contents of the files and printing the differences, if any.
        int numberOfDifferences = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < file1Tokens.length; i++)
        {
            if(!file1Tokens[i].equals(file2Tokens[i]))
            {
                numberOfDifferences++;
                System.out.println(file1Tokens[i] + " -- " + file2Tokens[i]);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of differences : " + numberOfDifferences);
        if(numberOfDifferences > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Files are not equal");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");
        }
    }
}
```

## DRY - Dont Repeat Yourself

If there is some common logic within you code, you can extract them to methods:

```java
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileComparatorExtractLogic {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        new FileComparatorExtractLogic().run();
    }
    
    public void run() throws IOException{
        //Getting the name of the files to be compared.
        BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter 1st input filename: ");
        String inputFilename1 = stdinReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd input filename: ");
        String inputFilename2 = stdinReader.readLine();

        String[] file1Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename1);
        String[] file2Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename2);

        //comparing the contents of the files and printing the differences, if any.
        int numberOfDifferences = 0;
        for(int m = 0; m < file1Tokens.length; m++)
        {
            if(!file1Tokens[m].equals(file2Tokens[m]))
            {
                numberOfDifferences++;
                System.out.println(file1Tokens[m] + " -- " + file2Tokens[m]);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of differences : " + numberOfDifferences);
        if(numberOfDifferences > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Files are not equal");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");
        }
    }
    
    public String[] getTokensFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        
        String fileLines = "";
        String fileLine;
        
        while((fileLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
            fileLines += fileLine;

        StringTokenizer fileTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(fileLines);
        String[] tokens = new String[10000];
        for(int l = 0; l < 10000; l++)
        {
            tokens[l] = "";
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (fileTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            tokens[i] = fileTokenizer.nextToken();;
            i++;
        }
        
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

## Streams

As of Java 8, [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [Lambdas](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips) where added, and they help us make our code shorter are more readable:

```java
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FileComparatorWithStreams {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        new FileComparatorWithStreams().run();
    }
    
    public void run() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter 1st input filename: ");
        String inputFilename1 = stdinReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd input filename: ");
        String inputFilename2 = stdinReader.readLine();

        List<String> file1Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename1);
        List<String> file2Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename2);

        // There is probably some way to do this with streams, but I cannot think of an elegant one right now
        int numberOfDifferences = 0;
        int smallestSize = Math.min(file1Tokens.size(), file2Tokens.size());
        String token1, token2;
        for (int i = 0; i < smallestSize; i++) {
            token1 = file1Tokens.get(i);
            token2 = file2Tokens.get(i);
            if (!token1.equals(token2)) {
                numberOfDifferences++;
                System.out.println(token1 + " -- " + token2);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No. of differences: " + numberOfDifferences);
        if(numberOfDifferences > 0) {
            System.out.println("Files are not equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");
        }
    }
    
    public List<String> getTokensFromFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        return fileReader.lines()
        .map(line -> Collections.list(new StringTokenizer(line)).stream()
                .map(s -> (String) s))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

## Exception and Resources handling

```java
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FileComparatorExceptionAndResourceHandling {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new FileComparatorExceptionAndResourceHandling().run();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        String inputFilename1;
        String inputFilename2;
        
        try (BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Enter 1st input filename: ");
            inputFilename1 = stdinReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter 2nd input filename: ");
            inputFilename2 = stdinReader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Unexpected exception ocurred while reading from stdi: {}\n", e);
            return;
        }

        List<String> file1Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename1);
        List<String> file2Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename2);

        int smallestSize = Math.min(file1Tokens.size(), file2Tokens.size());
        if (smallestSize == 0) {
            System.err.println("The given files are empty or could not be read");
        } else {
             // There is probably some way to do this with streams, but I cannot think of an elegant one right now
            int numberOfDifferences = 0;
            String token1, token2;
            for (int i = 0; i < smallestSize; i++) {
                token1 = file1Tokens.get(i);
                token2 = file2Tokens.get(i);
                if (!token1.equals(token2)) {
                    numberOfDifferences++;
                    System.out.println(token1 + " -- " + token2);
                }
            }
    
            System.out.println("No. of differences: " + numberOfDifferences);
            if(numberOfDifferences > 0) {
                System.out.println("Files are not equal");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public List<String> getTokensFromFile(String filename) {
        List<String> tokens;
        
        // A try-with-resources ensures the reader will be closed
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            tokens = fileReader.lines()
            .map(line -> Collections.list(new StringTokenizer(line)).stream()
                    .map(s -> (String) s))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Unexpected IOException ocurred while reading file {}: {}\n", filename, e);
            tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

## Divide and Conquer

The `run` method is starting to get a bit complex. We can divide it into smaller chuncks to make it easier to read:

```java
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FileComparatorDivideAndConquer {
    
    private String inputFilename1;
    private String inputFilename2;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new FileComparatorDivideAndConquer().run();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        requestFilesToCompare();
        if (inputFilename1 == null || inputFilename2 == null) {
            return;
        }

        List<String> file1Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename1);
        List<String> file2Tokens = getTokensFromFile(inputFilename2);

        
        int smallestSize = Math.min(file1Tokens.size(), file2Tokens.size());
        if (smallestSize == 0) {
            System.err.println("The files could not be read, or are empty");
        } else {
            int numberOfDifferences = calculateFileDifferences(file1Tokens, file2Tokens, smallestSize);
            System.out.println("No. of differences: " + numberOfDifferences);
            if(numberOfDifferences > 0) {
                System.out.println("Files are not equal");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getTokensFromFile(String filename) {
        List<String> tokens;
        
        // A try-with-resources ensures the reader will be closed
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            tokens = fileReader.lines()
            .map(line -> Collections.list(new StringTokenizer(line)).stream()
                    .map(s -> (String) s))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Unexpected IOException ocurred while reading file {}: {}\n", filename, e);
            tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        return tokens;
    }
    
    private void requestFilesToCompare() {
        try (BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Enter 1st input filename: ");
            inputFilename1 = stdinReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter 2nd input filename: ");
            inputFilename2 = stdinReader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Unexpected exception ocurred while reading from stdi: {}\n", e);
        }
    }
    
    private int calculateFileDifferences(List<String> file1Tokens, List<String> file2Tokens, int smallestSize) {
        // There is probably some way to do this with streams, but I cannot think of an elegant one right now
        int numberOfDifferences = 0;
        String token1, token2;
        for (int i = 0; i < smallestSize; i++) {
            token1 = file1Tokens.get(i);
            token2 = file2Tokens.get(i);
            if (!token1.equals(token2)) {
                numberOfDifferences++;
                System.out.println(token1 + " -- " + token2);
            }
        }
        return numberOfDifferences;
    }
}
```